# mailcore2 IMAPIdleOperation stops receiving mails after 5 mins with Android library

Tags: android, mailcore2

mailcore2 IMAPIdleOperation stops receiving mails after 5 mins with android mailcore2  library. can anyone please provide me the sample code how to handle Imap connection for a long time.

Here is my code

```
public class ImapIdleNotification extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    startIdle();


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.v(TAG,"Service killed");


}

public void startIdle() {

    final IMAPIdleOperation imapIdleOperation = MessagesSyncManager.singleton().session.idleOperation("INBOX", 1888 );

        imapIdleOperation.start(new OperationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void succeeded() {

                Log.v("Mailcore","...................Received new mail.........."+);

            }

            @Override
            public void failed(MailException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    });
}

}
```

IDlE operation stops when the message display on the console.

```
2-27 17:34:32.461 4910-4910/com.crm.mail I/MCOperationQueue.cpp: trying to quit 0xb4a07c00
12-27 17:34:32.462 4910-4934/com.crm.mail I/MCOperationQueue.cpp: stopping 0xb4a07c00
12-27 17:34:32.462 4910-4910/com.crm.mail I/MCOperationQueue.cpp: thread stopped 0xb4a07c00
12-27 17:34:32.462 4910-4934/com.crm.mail I/MCOperationQueue.cpp: cleanup thread 0xb4a07c00
```

Comment: You need to interrupt the IDLE operation every once in a while to prevent the server from timing out.

Comment: @Dinh Viêt Hoà Thanks for the quick answer. sometimes IDLE operation will not sustain for 1 min and stops immediately after receiving a first mail.

Comment: That's what IDLE operation is about ... notifying when you receive an email.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I have updated my question also included app log.  IDLE operation stops receiving mails as and when it got a new mail. After digging deep I came to know that the current running thread is getting killed in MCOperationQueue

Comment: Could you update your question with code?

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I have updated my question with code.

Comment: What is "1888" in the code? Here, you should use the UID of the email that was last seen. Is the callback called?

Comment: 1888 is last seen UID. Idle listener works fine until it receives a first mail. Yes, callback is called